# Atomic rename, works on Linux is there a way to emulate it on windows & OSX?

Tags: filesystems, locking, atomic

Under linux, you can rename a file with overwrite.  For example, rename -f file_a file_b
Will overwrite file_b with file_a and it'll be atomic.

Under OS/X it seems that this should have worked, but it's buggy.
Under Windows, nope.
On network filesystems - probably not.

Is there a way to simulate this behaviour among cooperating processes?

For example, if I'm only needing this in a single process then an atomic rename function could be created that creates a mutex, does a delete file then a rename file and unlocks.  That should be able to work on all platforms.

However, across process it's a little more tricky.  I could do a machine wide mutex lock but that's not going to solve it for cooperating processes on different machines.

Could I simulate this with lock files?  If so, how do I do it reliably so if a process were to be prematurely ended it can cleanup, or I can recognize a lock file that is no longer valid and remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:  NTFS file system transaction support is deprecated. Leaving this answer for historical reasons, but alternatives are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx**

NFTS supports transactions on the FS.  So you can't do exactly what you want, but you can start a transaction, delete the file and then rename.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx

I should point out this requires Vista or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Passing on the windows, but mv -f is atomic rename on BSD (and probably OSX) if target and source share the same filesystem. I would imagine this restriction applies to linux as well as the operation of rename means the inode is moved to a different dir and inodes are unique per filesytem. I'm not sure what you're trying to prevent here: that two processes do the same rename, i.e. identical source and destination?

Comment: I'm wanting to prevent the case where the app opens a file that it expects to be there, but because of the file being renamed, gets zero length data.

Comment: That's a non-existent case. If you acquire the file handle or file descriptor, the inode does not change and you open the inode. where the file ends up in the FS hierarchy after you're done with it does not matter. Of course, I'm assuming that by app you mean an application, not a script that uses different commands to test for existence and open/read.

Comment: I agree, but is this true on windows etc.

Comment: Don't know about windows. It's quite easy to make tests though. Acquire file handle, Fork, make parent sleep(3), make child rename, make parent print.

Comment: Thanks, just need to find a windows machine to test that on.